# CARP Interface Doesn't Respond to Traffic

Tags: openbsd, load-balancing, haproxy

I have two OpenBSD boxes on running as Gen1 VMs on Hyper-V 2016; the VMs are split across two Hyper-V hosts. The NICs associated with the CARP pseudo interface do have MAC address spoofing enabled; the CARP pseudo interfaces have a static MAC address in Hyper-V. I'm unable to ping the CARP interface, but can ping the IP of the NICs which support the CARP pseudo interface. In addition, the CARP interface is correctly assigning MASTER/BACKUP and I can see CARP traffic from the OpenBSD box when using `tcpdump -ni hnv1` (the physical interface).

My `/etc/sysctl.conf` file is:

```
net.inet.carp.allow=1
net.inet.carp.preempt=1
net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
```

There's no change if I move them to the same Hyper-V host. Pf on the OpenBSD boxes is disabled.

HAProxy is performing as a TCP proxy for multiple web servers. I do not want/need offloading, etc. hence not operating as an HTTPS proxy; will also be load balancing an RDS box over tcp/443. HAProxy works if I target the IP for the FQDN at the non-CARP interface.

What else can I look at here? Are there any other groups I can look to for help with CARP? Most of the CARP information out there surrounds pfSense box configurations.

The switching infrastructure is simple. Both Hyper-V boxes are attached to an Ubnt ES-250W-PoE and there is a Ubnt ERLite as the router.

ERL (10.10.20.1/24 untagged; VLAN ID 1: 172.16.5.0/23; VLAN ID 4: 192.168.80.1/24) -> ES-250W (10.10.20.2; LACP bonds for Hyper-V boxes carry untagged, VLAN ID 1 & 4). Hyper-V boxes LACP switch passes on traffic, no IP assigned. OpenBSD boxes have `hnv0` on the untagged VLAN, assigned space in the 10.10.20.0/24 subnet. `hnv1` is used by the `carp0` pseudo interface. `hvn1` NICs use 192.168.80.2/24 and 192.168.80.3/24, for the respective OpenBSD VM. `carp0` is assigned at 192.168.80.21/24.

The `hnv1` NICs and `carp0` do not have a gateway address assigned. Web servers are on the VLAN ID 1 assigned subnet.

I can ping 192.168.80.2 and .3 from any location on the network. I cannot ping 192.168.80.21 from any location except for the OpenBSD boxes themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there must simply have been a bug in the CentOS 6.1 release build. I upgraded to -current from 7/13/2017 and CARP immediately began working with no other changes.